# Qual é a origem da expressão "fazer cu doce"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, origem

No Brasil eu já ouvi alguém dizer que "Fulano está fazendo cu doce" querendo dizer que tem a percepção de que Fulano está fingindo ser contrário a alguma coisa. Muitas vezes a expressão é usada também em situações chulas.

De onde vem esta expressão? Em Portugal ela também é utilizada?

Comment: Aqui em Portugal não se usa. Pelo menos, nunca ouvi. Nem sequer aos meus amigos brasileiros. É muito comum no Brasil?

Comment: Ao menos aqui em São Paulo se usa muito quando alguém quer topar alguma coisa mas fica se fazendo de difícil em vez de aceitar logo de cara.

Comment: @Jorge B Não, não é comum no Brasil.  Ouve-se muito pouco..  Talvez porque hoje em dia "se faça menos cu doce" do que antigamente.  E conforme escrevi **no comentário deletado**, o termo é chulo e por isso fica mais gravado na memória das pessoas, dando a impressão de que é muito usado.  Ouve-se uma vez e não se esquece.

Comment: Segue no link abaixo uma boa explicação, que condiz com o que já ouvi sendo utilizado: http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/cu+doce/

Comment: Eu já ouvi ser usada em Portugal, mas é muito raro e que me lembre foi só por alguém casado com alguém de família brasileira. A expressão é percebida cá, mas acho que raramente é usada.

Answer (score 2):

Essa expressão apareceu no final dos anos 60 (pelo menos no Rio de Janeiro) com o sentido de "atribuir-se um valor inexistente, totalmente além da realidade". Como se a pessoa tentasse convencer os demais ou acreditasse que seu ânus tem uma característica apreciada mas irreal. Por exemplo, uma pessoa é convidada para passar alguns dias numa casa de praia, mas quem convida o faz por cortesia, pouco lhe importa se será aceito. O convidado começa a questionar que confortos tem a casa, se receberá tudo o que desejar lá, como se estivesse pagando por um hotel 5 estrelas.

Answer (score -1):

Eu busquei uma explicação, pois tive a curiosidade de saber se esse termo teria se originado de "kudos" (do Grego) que juntamente com "gravitas" (do Latin) é muito usado em Inglês. Talvez, passou-se a escrevê-lo com "C": "cudos", mas se pronunciado aproximando-se da pronúncia original /kudóss/ seria fácil torná-lo no nosso velho e conhecido "cu doce"!

Comment: Bem-vindo, Edmundo. Essa resposta parece altamente especulativa e com pouca base — afinal qual seria a relação entre o significado da expressão em português o de "kudos"? É necessário uma justificativa mais sólida ou, idealmente, referências a evidências documentais e/ou obras de referência.